# 3D Touch peek view like that for pressing on a phone number

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3dtouch

When you deep press on a phone number for example, it shows a different style of peek view:

[image]

I'd like to know if there's a simple way of replicating this or if I have to set up all those views myself. I couldn't find anything in the documentation.